# Can I send out redemption/test codes for Windows 8 applications?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-rt

Is there a redemption/test code feature as a developer of a Windows 8 application?  So reviewers/testers don't have to pay for it?  Can't see a way to do this on the developer dashboard and haven't found a clear answer anywhere that says you can.

Answer (score 0):

No, no way to do that on the Windows Store, not even a beta store to do similar through beta invites. Windows Phone Store has a beta, though.

What you could do is pack it up, upload to dropbox or similar, and add a readme/howto for installation. This might be too much for a reviewer though, but maybe the setup procedure could be simplified?

Then there's also the time-limited trial you could set up on the Store?